# How to pass any html content to thymeleaf fragment without using the layout dialect?

Tags: html, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I wonder if you can leave the layout dialect out and use thymeleaf out of the box.
Currently you can define a fragment for example like follows:

```
<div th:fragment="my-custom-accordeon">
    <th:block th:insert="~{::h1}></th:block>
    <th:block th:insert="~{::section}></th:block>
</div>
```

Using this fragment you could simply use add an h1 tag and a section tag within the html snippet that is using the fragment from above. Both tags would be inserted as content to this fragment.

I am unsure if you can do the same with any content, without the need to define the tags, that would be passed to the fragment as content. I want to add any html content.
Currently I am using the layout dialect for this purpose but I would be very happy if I would't need to.

My custom accordeon with the layout dialect, that accepts any content looks like following

```
 <div layout:fragment="accordion(heading)">
    <h2>[[${heading}]]</h2>
    <div class="body">
      <th:block layout:fragment="accordion-content"></th:block>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And in my referring html file I am using it for example like:

```
<div layout:replace="~{/path/to/template.html :: accordion(heading='Example Heading')}">
  <th:block layout:fragment="accordion-content">
    <p>Maybe some p tag</p>
    <!-- maybe some table 
         maybe some nested accordion
         whatever i like 
    -->
   </th:block>
</div>
```

Can you achieve the same with plain thymeleaf without the layout or any other dialect?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Looking for the same :)

Comment: unfortunately not 

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and took a while to figure out. This works for me:

My example is a thymeleaf + tailwind + alpineJS modal component:

Template (`fragments/modals.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <th:block layout:fragment="modal" th:with="id=${id},isOpen=${isOpen}">
      <div
        th:x-data="|{ open: ${isOpen == true}, id: '${id}' }|"
        class="flex justify-center"
      >
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div
          x-show="open"
          style="display: none"
          x-on:keydown.escape.prevent.stop="open = false"
          class="fixed inset-0 z-30 overflow-y-auto"
          @modal.window="open = $event.detail === id"
        >
          <!-- Overlay -->
          <div
            x-show="open"
            x-transition.opacity
            class="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50"
          ></div>

          <!-- Panel -->
          <div
            x-show="open"
            x-transition:enter="transition ease-out sm:duration-200 duration-300"
            x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 sm:opacity-0 sm:scale-95 sm:translate-y-0 translate-y-8"
            x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 sm:scale-100 translate-y-0"
            x-transition:leave="transition ease-in sm:duration-100 duration-200"
            x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 sm:scale-100 translate-y-0"
            x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 sm:scale-95 sm:translate-y-0 translate-y-8"
            x-on:click="open = false"
            class="relative flex min-h-screen items-end justify-center px-1 py-2 sm:items-center sm:px-2"
            x-init="$watch('open', (value) => {
              if (value) {
                $nextTick(() => {
                  $focus.getFirst() && $focus.getFirst().focus()
                })
              }
            })"
          >
            <div
              x-on:click.stop
              x-trap.noscroll.inert="open"
              class="shadow-lg relative w-full max-w-8 overflow-y-auto rounded-xl bg-background-primary px-2 py-4 sm:rounded sm:px-4"
            >
              <th:block layout:fragment="modal-content">
                <!-- children goes here -->
              </th:block>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </th:block>
  </body>
</html>
```

Usage:

```
<th:block layout:include="fragments/modals :: modal(id='myModal')">
  <th:block layout:fragment="modal-content">
    <p>My modal content</p>
  </th:block>
</th:block>
```

or start the modal as open

```
<th:block layout:include="fragments/modals :: modal(id='myModal', isOpen=${someTrueVariableFromJava})">
```